# How to send a data on end point, when user leave your page?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to send a some data when user leaves my page or browser. Which events i should use? I am using react and axios, maybe there is some way to do it.

I tried to use the unload, beforeunload, and onbeforeunload event but it worked periodically. Sometimes it sends data but when I try to do it again, it doesn't work. And I don't need a popup/alert tab 'which asks user confirmation to close tab or not',  to appear when the page is about to close.

Answer (score 2):

I think when you want to send data when a user leaves your page or closes the browser, the `beforeunload` event is a commonly used approach.

Using `beforeunload` event can trigger a confirmation dialog in some browsers, and there's no guaranteed time for the network request to complete.

One alternative is to use the `unload` event, which is fired just before the page is unloaded. Keep in mind that, similar to `beforeunload`, the `unload` event is also limited in terms of reliability for sending data.

I add sample code using `unload`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const cleanup = async () => {
      try {
        await axios.post('your-api-endpoint', { yourData });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending data on unload:', error);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('unload', cleanup);

    return () => {
      cleanup();
      window.removeEventListener('unload', cleanup);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your component content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```